# macOS SDK dependency within dylib location

Tags: xcode, macos, dylib, mach-o

When building a macOS dylib against a particular macOS SDK version, how does that SDK dependency manifest within the dylib itself?  That is, what are the differences at the mach-o level in a dylib that was built against the 10.13 SDK vs the 10.14 SDK, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Literally it is versions of compatible dependent libraries, which are written into your dylib.

To see them open Terminal and run

```
# scrun otool -L _path_to_your_dylib
```

Comment: Plus the LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX structure.  Anything else that's relevant?  Investigating what it would take to change the SDK dependency directly without rebuilding.